# Form Validation in Rest Webservice

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jpa

I started building my first REST webservice in Java using Spring and JPA.

Now I'm trying to create sign-up service. I have no problem with sending a request containing all Entity fields what looks:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")  
public class User implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "login")
private String login;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@Column(name = "registration_date")
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookOwner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

But what to do in situation I want my registration form having only login, password and email fields and filling the rest user details would be optional - after confirmation of registration?

I consider using ModelMapper and creating separate classes for every form, but is there any better approach?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by my own using mentioned ModelMapper. I paste my code. Can be useful if someone's interested. Didn't make tests, but my DB looks fine and no exceptions are thrown.

```
 public class DTOMapper {
        private static final ModelMapper MAPPER = new ModelMapper();

        private DTOMapper(){}

        public static <S, T> T map(S source, Class<T> targetClass){
            return MAPPER.map(source, targetClass);
        }    
    }

@Service
@Transactional
public class SignUpService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public SignUpService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public User registerUser(SignUpForm form){
        if(userRepository.findByLogin(form.getLogin())!=null){
            throw new LoginAlreadyUsedException(form.getLogin());
        }

        if(userRepository.findByEmail(form.getEmail())!=null){
            throw new EmailAlreadyUsedException(form.getEmail());
        }

        User user = DTOMapper.map(form, User.class);

        User saved = userRepository.save(user);

        return DTOMapper.map(saved, User.class);
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class SignUpForm implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 5)
    private String login;

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 7)
    private String password;

    //todo email validation
    @NotEmpty
    private String email;
}


@RestController
public class SignUpController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SignUpController.class);

    @Autowired
    private SignUpService signUpService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/signup")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@RequestBody @Valid SignUpForm form, BindingResult errors){

        if(errors.hasErrors()){
            throw new InvalidRequestException(errors);
        }

        signUpService.registerUser(form);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(form, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```